# Problem with function from theme-settings.php in sub-theme

Tags: 7

I want to create the sub-theme of my custom theme but I have the problem with the function from theme-settings.php.

I have a few `managed_file` fields in my theme settings and my submit function for one of them looks like:

```
function my_theme_settings_form_submit_home_back(&$form, $form_state)
{
    $previous = file_load($form_state['home_back_before']);
    $image_fid = $form_state['values']['home_back'];
    $image = file_load($image_fid);
    if (is_object($image)) {
        // Check to make sure that the file is set to be permanent.
        if ($image->status == 0) {
            // Update the status.
            $image->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
            // Save the update.
            file_save($image);
            // Add a reference to prevent warnings.
            file_usage_add($image, 'my_theme', 'theme', 1);
        }
    }
    if (is_object($previous)) {
        if ($previous->fid !== @$image->fid) {
            file_usage_delete($previous, 'my_theme', 'theme', 1);
            file_delete($previous);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great in the theme but when I try to change any theme setting on my sub-theme I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function my_theme_settings_form_submit_home_back() in
```

Any change in the main theme works without problems.

Can you give me some idea what the problem is and help me to fix it?

Comment: Had the same issue found answer here http://ghosty.co.uk/2014/03/managed-file-upload-in-drupal-theme-settings/

Comment: Hi Tyrell, thank you for the answer, but it is not the problem that I have. I'm doing the same thing as described on the link that you provide, but problem is with the child theme, look through my question again...